# Definition of meromorphic form.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I stumbled upon the term *meromorphic 2-form* on a complex manifold. How is that defined? I know what a holomorphic 2-form is, but what does it mean to be meromorphic? A meromorphic function is one that can be $\infty$ at isolated points, but I can't imagine how a form is meromorphic.

Comment: A section of $\wedge^2 \Omega^\mathrm{hol}_M$ over a dense open subset maybe.

Comment: In local coordinates, a holomorphic $2$-form looks like $\sum_{i\ne j} f(z_1,...,z_n)dz_i\wedge dz_j$ with $f$ holomorphic. If you allow $f$ meromorphic, you obtain the notion of a meromorphic $2$-form. I think this coincides with the notion suggested by @AlexYoucis but you may or may not find it more amenable to your way of thinking.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Do we need to assume the section near the undefined loci behaves like 'pole' rather than 'essential singularity'? Because when define meromorphic function, we do need the isolated singularities are poles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've taken calculus, you have more than likely already met some meromorphic differential forms: for example, we often see the differential form $$\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$$ and get to know its properties when discussing line integrals. This is exactly an example of a meromorphic differential: you can tell because the coefficients of the $dx$ and $dy$ terms are meromorphic functions. Every meromorphic differential looks like this in local coordinates: since you're asking about a 2-form, yours will look like $\sum f dx_idx_j$ for $f$ a meromorphic function and the $x$s as local coordinates.

If you're interested in a sheafier description of this, you can think about rational sections in algebraic geometry which are exactly the analogue of meromorphic sections in complex analysis. You can either think about tensoring your bundle/sheaf with the sheaf of meromorphic/rational functions and taking a global section, or think about taking a regular section on some dense open set. I leave it to you to verify that these are really the same things.